# Reformat Date Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongoose

I am writing an application in JavaScript (Node.js to be precise) and I currently have a date string formatted like this in a mongoose database:

2013-11-19T00:10:00-08:00

I want to run a query on the database by finding all results that have times occurring on that given day

It needs to work on all dates, not just the above example

Comment: To query a mongo db by date: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: OP changed question.*

```
var start = new Date(2013,11,19);
var end = new Date (2013,11,20);
db.collection.find({dateTimeField: {$gte: start, $lt: end}});
```

Thanks to gilly3's comment on OP highlighting: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/

---

Maybe there's something I'm missing since you're using mongoose... but:

```
var dateTimeStr = '2013-11-19T00:10:00-08:00';
var dateTime = new Date(dateTimeStr);
var formatted = d.getFullYear()+'-'+(d.getMonth()+1)+'-'+d.getDate();
```

The date-time value you have is a standard ISO 8601 which is parsable internally by the Date object.

I'm also not sure why you have a date-time stamp stored (or being fetched) as a string. MongoDB has the ability to store a Date object.

See [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript) for more details on formatting dates.

Comment: @user2864740 the tag is nodejs and mongoose, wouldn't that hint to server-side in which case multi-browser compat isn't a problem.

Comment: Thanks, zamnuts. I just edited my question. I actually want to know how to query the database for all times happening on a given day. For example I want to run a query for all times occurring today. The database values are stored like this at the moment:
2013-11-19T00:10:00-08:00

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows internal command `for` with `delims` and `tokens` if you'd like to.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateTimeString = '2013-11-19T00:10:00-08:00';
// substring + indexOf solution
console.log("1)", dateTimeString.substring(0, dateTimeString.indexOf("T")));
// regex.match solution
console.log("2)", dateTimeString.match(/^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/)[0]);
```